# Kernel messages in syslog, what's their meaning?

Tags: fedora, kernel

Recently, after a kernel update, I started getting these messages on my terminal:

```
Message from syslogd@andromeda at Mar 20 11:26:23 ... 
kernel:page:fffffa51ae43a000 count:0 mapcount:0
mapping:0000000000000000 index:0x1

Message from syslogd@andromeda at Mar 20 11:26:24 ...
kernel:flags:
0x17fffe00000090(waiters|dirty)
```

What's the meaning of these? There's not much information in it...

Comment: That's strange, messages like those are usually generated when the kernel panics... are you seeing them regularly or did this happen just once?

Comment: Is it a raspberry, or a normal VM? What version is the kernel? Have you seen the release notes to see what is new there?

Comment: @MarcoBonelli I saw them a couple of times while stuff was running and broke nothing. Now I am seeing it also at boot and the boot doesn't finish.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro This is 64bit intel i7 (16 cores) based server.